# PHP: How can I make a webservice that respondes with XML and an image?

Tags: php, iphone, web-services, image

My PHP abilities are almost non-existent and I am trying to make a very simple REST webservice. The service at present queries a database and returns an image in a 'application/octet-stream' response. I am calling this webservice via ASIHTTP (a REST iPhone framework) which is returning the image perfectly fine :)

Is there any way to make the PHP service return an image AND an XML file? I am thinking the only way to do this is to write the image byte array directly into the XML file. If so - how do I do this with PHP?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If ASIHTTP supports this, you could try embedding the image data in the XML, but you'd have to read the relevant documentation first. You can't simply dump a bunch of binary data into an XML file, you need to convert it to something like base64 first.

IMO, a better (more robust) approach is to send both files independently: make one request for the XML, which may contain an ID or something for the image, and then another request to get the image itself.

Apart from more robust code, you will also be able to parse the entire XML before the image is fully loaded. Seeing how images are typically much larger than XML messages, the difference is going to be noticable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way would be to base64 encode your image data with PHP and decode it on your iPhone. See the [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) manual page - the first comment describes how to use it to read an image.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to take the binary data and (for example) [`base64_encode`](https://www.php.net/base64_encode) it, embed that in your XML, and then when you receive it you can base64_decode it using `+ (NSData *)decodeBase64WithString:(NSString *)strBase64 {` from [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour):

```
NSData *data = [Base64 decodeBase64WithString:strBase64];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: I am having problems using base64_encode. If I use it on a string it encodes fine. If I use it on the image binary data it doesn't return anything :/ I know there is binary data as I can echo this to the page and it looks like a lot of misc characters.

Comment: Ok.. So it turns out it works if I apply chunk_split to the binary64. How strange.